# Create list with two queries

Tags: apex, query, list

i have this query:

```
Set<Id> drIds = new Set<Id>();
List<custom_Object__c> dr = [SELECT id, name FROM custom_Object__c WHERE AcountId__c =: accountId];
for(custom_Object__c drl :dr) {
    drIds.add(drl.id);
}

List<ContentDocumentLink> cd = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN: drIds];
```

How can i get the custom_Object__c id, name and ContentDocumentId in the same list?

i also tried a subquery like this:

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> cd = new List<ContentDocumentLink>([SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN ( SELECT Id FROM custom_Object__c WHERE AccountId__c =: accountId )]);
```

But i cant get the subquery value.

What can i do?

Comment: A brief note: Your second query uses a _semi-join_. A semi-join helps to filter results of the overall query, but you can only query the Id or relationship fields. Even if you could query more fields, we can't fetch the results of a semi-join from the results of the overall query.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedEntityId` on the `ContentDocumentLink` object is an example of a polymorphic relationship field. Where normal relationship fields can only point to a single Id of a specific SObject, polymorphic relationship fields can point to a single Id of one of *many* SObjects.

For a period of time, Salesforce did not give us any tools to query related data from polymorphic relationships, but now (since Winter '14, I think?) we do.

[Working with polymorphic relationships in SOQL queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm) is the official documentation, which does a decent job of showing how to do it.

In your case, your query will end up looking like

```
[SELECT TYPEOF LinkedEntity
    WHEN Custom_Object__c
        THEN Id, Name
    END
FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId IN 
    (SELECT Id FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds)
]
```

To access the information from `Custom_Object__c`, you'll need to use `instanceOf` or something similar (like `LinkedEntity.getSObjectType() == Custom_Object__c.SObjetType`) before it's generally safe to start using dot notation like normal

```java
for(ContentDocumentLink cdl = :[SELECT ContentDocumentId, TYPEOF LinkedEntity
    WHEN Custom_Object__c
        THEN Id, Name
    END
FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId IN 
    (SELECT Id FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds)
]){
    if(cdl.LinkedEntity instanceOf Custom_Object__c){
        system.debug(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
        system.debug(cdl.LinkedEntity.Id);
        system.debug(cdl.LinkedEntity.Name);
    }
}
```

You might consider creating an inner class (with member variables for the ContentDocumentId, the Custom Object Id, and the Custom Object Name) to make it easier to handle this data in other places. That way, only the `for` loop that initially processes the results would need to concern itself with the additional complexity you get from dealing with polymorphic relationships (i.e. you would create instances of this inner class inside of the for loop instead of simply printing the information to the debug log).

Comment: nice! and how do i add it to a list to call it like system.debug(mylist[0]) to get the values?